# How can I display older emails on my Samsung Note 4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4

My Samsung Note 4 only loads the last 7 days of emails.  How can I display older emails?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the mail configuration. For instance in Gmail, you can go to settings and configure how many days of  mail you want to be displayed.

This has nothing to do with your phone model or Android Version